# How to remove a blank page at the beginning of the book?

Tags: books

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}


\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\selectlanguage{polish}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

gg


\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{ xxx }


\end{document}
```

As a result I get two pages at the beginning 1 with gg written 1 blank and then the chaper page. How do I remove the blank page?

Comment: Note that you can format code as code by indenting 4 spaces (easy way: highlight the code and press '{}' button).

Comment: Is your document going to be printed double-sided? If so, pass `openany` as an option to the class. If not, use `oneside`. You don't need the `\selectlanguage` line, by the way.

Answer (score 2):

The `book` class defaults to a layout designed for double-sided printing. By default, chapters start on odd-numbered (right-hand) pages. Hence, a blank page will be left if necessary to accommodate this layout.

There are two ways to avoid this depending on your document.

If you are printing double-sided but would prefer chapters to start on even-numbered pages where appropriate, pass `openany` as an option to the document class:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
```

If you are producing a single-sided document, then you want to override the double-sided default instead:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
```